# iPhone SDK: how to properly handle errors of NSBundle resource loading?

Tags: iphone

I'm using NSBundle resources to load some media:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:someValue ofType@"someType"]];
```

if there is no resource found, the url value, of course, remains valid and using it would cause application crash, so the simple check

```
if(!url) { //or even (!mediaPlayer), or (url == nil)
    //show alert box
}
```

does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to compare the result of pathForResource:ofType: against nil, and handle the error at that point.

```
NSString *pathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathforResource:@"name" ofType:@"ext"];
if (!pathString) {
   // Handle error
}

NSURL *theURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathString];
```